# How to sum numbers in array by index in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
const array = [6,2,6,7,5,9];
```

I want sum of all numbers till `7` in array

I tried `.reduce` but it gave me sum of whole array,
How can I do that so?

Comment: Can you include your attempt(s)? -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You should include the code that you have attempted. But I would `slice()` the array first, then try `reduce()`

Comment: Do you want to sum the numbers as they appear in order up to 7 (6, 2, 6), or all the numbers in the array that are lower than 7 (6, 2, 6, 5)?

Comment: Yes,  sum of all numbers upto 7

Comment: In that case, I'd `filter()` your array, then `reduce()`

Comment: @AtulYadav, that didn't really answer my question. Do you want 14 as an answer, or 19?

Comment: 21? I mean add all numbers upto 7 like 6+2+6+7=21 in array

Comment: "Up to and including" then :)

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to jump through a lot of hoops with `reduce`. You'd need to [find the index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) of `7`, then [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) up to that index, and then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the spliced array. Muy complicado!

It's much simpler to create a `sum` variable, and [loop over the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement). Add each number to the sum, and when the number is `7` break the loop.

It's worth noting this strategy wouldn't work for duplicate numbers like `6` for example because which `6` would you choose?

```js
const arr = [6, 2, 6, 7, 5, 9];

let sum = 0;

for (const n of arr) {
  sum += n;
  if (n === 7) break;
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is doable with just a for loop:

```js
const array = [6, 2, 6, 7, 5, 9];
let sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  sum += array[i];
  if (array[i] == 7) break;
}

// outputs the sum of [6,2,6,7], which is 21
console.log(sum);
```

Here we take the sum of numbers till 7 to mean the sum of all numbers in our array up until the first instance of 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. This is going to loop trow and store the sum until it's 7.

```
const array = [6, 2, 6, 7, 5, 9]
let sum = 0

array.forEach((number) => {
  if (sum <= 7) sum += number
})

console.log(sum) // Output: 8
```

Comment: I don't think he is looking for this because he mentioned until the number reaches 7 and in that case the result should have been 21 instead of 8

Comment: This is not what OP is asking

Answer (score 0):

Do write the following code before you reduce it!

```
const arr1 = array.slice(0,4);
```

and then reduce arr1. you will get your desired Answer!
oh and please change the name of the constant however you want!

Comment: What if you didn't know what index `7` was at?

Comment: then use find(),indexOf(),and then slice and reduce if you want to use array methods that is! as i have done in the other answer i have given

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
const array = [6, 2, 6, 7, 5, 9];
const found = array.find(element => element >= 7);
const newArr = array.indexOf(found);
const arr1 = array.slice(0,(newArr + 1));
const sum = 0;
const result = arr1.reduce(
  (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue,
  sum
);

console.log(result); //output 21
```

Comment: `findIndex` might be a neater solution than using `find` and then `indexOf`.